# Simple Database Design - Employee Manager Relationship

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm new to database design, and I was curious if I am approaching a problem the wrong way.

So, I'm creating a simple application with the requirement of persisting an Employee entity. Some Employees may be Managers with a list of Employees that server under them. What is the best practice to create this scenario in database design?

Currently I have two tables. One table called employee, which contains columns for ID, name, etc. I have a second table defining a manager-employee relationship. This table contains a column MANAGER_ID, and a column EMPLOYEE_ID. To figure out what employees a manager has, I have to join with this relationship table, and grab each unique employee_id for that specific manager_id. Is this a good way to do this?

If not, can you explain why it is bad, and an example of better design?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that you're talking about a *relational* database, this seems an entirely plausible. The employer / employee relationship database example is very common and an internet search shouldn't take too long to validate your design.

If you're new to database design, you could do a it worse than to get yourself a decent book on the subject such as "Handbook of Relational Database Design" by Fleming / von Halle, which is pretty old but gives a good grounding in the basics which a surprising large amount of programmers are unaware of. That's just one decent book on the subject - there are plenty of others.

Comment: Another book I've heard good things about is, "Database Design for Mere Mortals."

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to use a self-join, viz. each row in the employee table has an additional column manager_id. You then do a self-join when querying

See an example (for your exact case) here:

https://blog.udemy.com/sql-self-join/

Not sure if there are any benefits of one approach versus the other.